# Spring Boot Rest API JSON return null

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I have REST controller to submit score to database. @Requestbody is a Game object.

Comment: Plz add more informations about your problem next time ..:)

Comment: hi toomas! Why did you delete your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove @JsonIgnore from Player.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "playerId")
private Player player;
```